# Memory leak while using google map API in java script

Tags: javascript, wpf, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API v3 for my C# WPF project. I have created a browser control and trying to mark the location using markers in java script. For every one second, I am updating the markers. This works fine, but there is a serious increase in memory.

I feel this is because every time it needs to be created a new marker as below:

```
var currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: currentLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 6,
                    strokeColor: 'black',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                    strokeWeight: 1.0,
                    fillColor: markerColor,
                    fillOpacity: 0.6
                }
            });
```

The memory gradually increase and the application hangs after some time. Is there any way to clear the memory ?

Comment: could you post a working sample of your app? the code above does not seems to have any issue.

Comment: If you are just changing position of marker on update than you can reuse the marker and set new position using `marker.setPosition()`.